# Placing images aligned horizontally and equally spaced with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I'm customizing a beamer template and would like to insert three images in the title page, all aligned horizontally and equally spaced.

I've been struggling a lot with options for `\node` but haven't come to a good solution.

I'm using basically

```
\node[anchor=north west](img1) at (0,\slideheight-0.2cm)
    {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{img1.png}};

\node[anchor=north west](img2) at (2cm,\slideheight-0.2cm)
    {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{img2.png}};
```

And trying to tweak distances, but that is A Very Bad Idea™.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `node`s for this. Just `\includegraphics` should do the job with few `\hfill`s. However, this can be done with nodes. Place the first node at 0, second at `0.5\textwidth` third at `\textwidth`. Now choose uniform width for nodes by `text width` which I have set at `0.3333\textwidth`. Then select the proper anchor for each node as in the following code and `align=center`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  X\hrulefill X

  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
  X\hrulefill X

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[anchor=north west,text width=0.3333\textwidth,align=center](img1) at
           (0,\textheight-0.2cm)
           {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
     \node[anchor=north,text width=0.3333\textwidth,align=center](img2) at
           (0.5\textwidth,\textheight-0.2cm)
           {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
     \node[anchor=north east,text width=0.3333\textwidth,align=center](img2) at
           (\textwidth,\textheight-0.2cm)
           {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I needed a solution with nodes because the title page has some Tikz customization such as filling most of it with a color. The plain `\includegraphics` didn't work for me, I really had to use the nodes.